# How to recover fitting values from logit transformation

Tags: logistic

I have dependent variable `y` belongs to (0,1).I want to use logit transformation of this variable `ln [y/(1-y)])`. My question is to how recover fitted value of `y` from fitted values of `ln [y/(1-y)]`. As logit transformation is not linear transformation of dependent variable, it is not just inverse of logit.

Comment: Pedantically not, the usual rules of algebra yield $0$ given $y / 1 - y$. We know that is not what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a fractional logit or [another approach](https://www.stata.com/meeting/germany10/germany10_buis.pdf) suited to this kind of limited dependent variable. There might be another way to avoid the re-transformation bias, and often it is not too severe, but why not do something simpler?

Here's an example using Stata:

```
. use wedderburn, clear 

. drop if yield == 1 | yield ==0
(4 observations deleted)

. /* Fractional Logit */
. fraclogit yield
-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
fractional logit results                                       Obs  = 86     
                                                               rmse = 2.70245
                                                               df   = 1      
                                                           pearson  = 229.708
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       yield |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   -1.28442   .1772677    -7.25   0.000    -1.631858   -.9369815
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // equivalent glm command for fraclogit
. glm yield, link(logit) family(binomial) vce(robust) nolog 
note: yield has noninteger values

Generalized linear models                         Number of obs   =         86
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =         85
                                                  Scale parameter =          1
Deviance         =  38.89817511                   (1/df) Deviance =   .4576256
Pearson          =  39.00377373                   (1/df) Pearson  =   .4588679

Variance function: V(u) = u*(1-u/1)               [Binomial]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u/(1-u))             [Logit]

                                                  AIC             =   .8878371
Log pseudolikelihood = -37.17699701               BIC             =  -339.7213

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       yield |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   -1.28442   .1772676    -7.25   0.000    -1.631858   -.9369814
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, gen(yield_hat_fl)
Warning: prediction constant over observations.

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =         86
Model VCE    : Robust

Expression   : Predicted mean yield, predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .2167988   .0300995     7.20   0.000     .1578048    .2757928
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. /* Demonstrate re-transformation bias */
. gen double logit_yield = logit(yield)

. reg logit_yield, robust

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =         86
                                                F(0, 85)          =       0.00
                                                Prob > F          =          .
                                                R-squared         =     0.0000
                                                Root MSE          =     2.7107

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
 logit_yield |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |  -2.540454   .2923012    -8.69   0.000    -3.121627   -1.959281
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, expression(invlogit(xb())) gen(yield_hat_tols)
Warning: prediction constant over observations.

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =         86
Model VCE    : Robust

Expression   : invlogit(xb())

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .0730704   .0197979     3.69   0.000     .0342673    .1118736
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // or equivalently
. predict double logit_yield_hat, xb

. generate double yield_hat_tols2 = invlogit(logit_yield_hat)

. mean yield*

Mean estimation                      Number of obs   =         86

-----------------------------------------------------------------
                |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
----------------+------------------------------------------------
          yield |   .2167988   .0300995      .1569529    .2766448
  yield_hat_fl1 |   .2167988          0             .           .
yield_hat_tols1 |   .0730704          0             .           .
yield_hat_tols2 |   .0730704          0             .           .
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the `invlogit()` transformed OLS results don't match the sample mean at all, whereas the fractional logit predictions match the mean perfectly.

Comment: Here is [an example](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800800212) where the bias is not too bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can still recover $y$: use the inverse function of the logit function. The function isn’t linear, but it’s still invertible.

The inverse function is the [logistic sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) $\sigma$, which is frequently available in software packages.

This is indeed the inverse; that is,
$$
y = \sigma(\mathrm{logit}(y))
\text{.}
$$

Run your fitted log-odds values through the sigmoid function and you’ll get the $y$s you need.

Comment: This re-transformation approach can run into some trouble for Jensen's Inequality reasons. My answer gives an example where it is bad, though to be fair, it does not always perform this poorly.